# How to portably check for `crypt` failure?

Tags: password

Some systems are unfortunately integrating a new `crypt` implementation from *libxcrypt* which, when the function fails, instead of returning a null pointer, returns a "failure token" string that starts with `*`, such as `*0`.

It's not clear whether that specific string is guaranteed. When we look a the *libxcrypt* code, it looks like this feature can be turned off at compile time, in which case the API functions only check for a leading `*` character coming from the lower-level routines, and turn it into a null return. That suggests application code should do the same; just check for the `*` and not assume any specific token.

My question is, do other `crypt` implementations guarantee never to return a leading `*` under any circumstances (other than failure, by way of imitating *libxcrypt*?)

If we do this:

```
if (ret != NULL && ret[0] != '*') {
  /* we have a valid result */
} else {
  /* crypt failed */
}
```

Is that cool? Or do we have to distinguish whether the `crypt` we are using is the *libxcrypt* one, and only do the check in that case?

(One idea: we can also set `errno` to zero, and only conclude that the leading `*` is a failure if `errno` has changed to `EINVAL`.)

Comment: How it works is that the failure token has to be different from the *salt* argument. (Called *setting* in libxcrypt.).  The obvious way to meet the requirement is always to use `*0`, except when the *setting* argument is `*0`; in that case use `*1`.   And that's exactly what the implementation does.

Comment: You could also check the string length, after all a string this short can't possibly represent a proper password hash. Even for just 128bit, the ascii encoded hash would have to be over 20 chars long. You could hash the password twice, the results should differ (random salt). You could validate the password, it should work for the original password and fail for an altered one (append a character or change 1 bit in the last character). However if you test things this way you're really not trusting the library much...